# Trimming fastq.gz files

Tags: sequence, fastq

I have multiple fastq.gz files I want to keep only the first 8 bases from fastq and remove the rest

```
input
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTTTG
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFF<BFFFIIFFFFFIIIBFFFFFIIFIIIIIFFBFFFFFF


output
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAA
+
#0<BFFFF
```

I tried Fastx and seqk - no luck. What should I do?